# How do I make UILabel as the NavigationBar's rightBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

can anyone help me how to make a UILabel as NavigationBar's rightBarButtonItem?

I tried doing UIBarButtonItem's initWithCustomView on the UIView with UILabel but crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following code.

```
 UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260,6,55,32)];
  yourLabel.text = @"Ashu";
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:yourLabel];
```

Please notify if it works..

Answer (score 2):

Here is some sample code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 65.0, 30.0)];
label.text = @"Text";
barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:label];
```

Then you would simply set "barButton" equal to the right navigation item

Answer (score 1):

for do this:

```
yourButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30) ];
    [yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourmethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 8, 40, 30)];
    yourLabel.text = @"your Text";
    yourLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    yourLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    yourLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f];
    [yourLabel sizeToFit];
    [yourButton addSubview:yourLabel];

[yourButton sizeToFit]; 

    yourBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourButton];
     self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourBarButton;
```